# Redirecting to a blank page using a click event

Tags: android, gridview

I'm trying to redirect my current page to an empty page with an `onItemClick` event, but an error occurred.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_universiteler, container, false);
    GridView listView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    ((GridView) listView).setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Uri link = Uri.parse(Site[position]);
            Intent tara = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DEFAULT, link);
            startActivity(tara);
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand anything you put there. Can you make a clean question? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Sir summary as not directed to the page I want a null is directed to a page without any error

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_universiteler, container, false);
                GridView listView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
            ((GridView) listView).setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Uri link = Uri.parse(Site[position]);
                    Intent tara = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DEFAULT, link);
                    startActivity(tara);
                }
            });
            return rootView;
        }
```